# Converting a regular compute engine VM instances to a AI Platform Notebook instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Is there anyway I convert/add Jupyter Lab to an existing VM. This VM was created under Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances. When I go to AI Platforms -> Notebooks, I do not see this instance, so I'm assuming it is not setup to use Jupyter Lab. However, the settings on this VM should be more than sufficient to run Jupyter Lab, so I was hoping to add this functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of AI Platform Notebooks is to be a managed service for Jupyter Notebook. Please have a look at the documentation [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks):

> **Managed JupyterLab notebook instances**
>
> **AI Platform Notebooks is a managed service** that offers an integrated
>   and secure JupyterLab environment for data scientists and machine
>   learning developers to experiment, develop, and deploy models into
>   production. Users can create instances running JupyterLab that come
>   pre-installed with the latest data science and machine learning
>   frameworks in a single click.

Also, if you check managed VM you'll found the description of the image:

```
Google, Deep Learning Image: Container Base, m50, A Debian based image with Docker and NVIDIA-Docker support for custom containers with Deep Learning Image integration.
```

and this image is different from the image you have on your VM.

As result, unfortunately, **you're not able to use your existing VM for such purposes**.

You can try to file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) if you really want to be able to do it.